# How to record screen in Ubuntu 22.04/23.04 through the command line

Tags: command-line, gnome, 22.04, desktop-recording, video-recording

I use Ubuntu's built-in screen recorder. Here is a screenshot of the application:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz3tb.png)

Now, I would like to know how to achieve the same screen recording action using the command line. I'm specifically interested in recording a video rather than capturing a single image.

I prefer to use the built-in tool rather than relying on a third-party tool for safety reasons.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. As of now there doesn't seem to be a way to record the screen using Terminal without installing any third party software. The default screen recorder can be opened using  Ctrl+Shift+Alt+R key combination if in case you missed. However you can use reliable third party software `ffmpeg` for screen recording if you're requirement is to record your screen using command line (X11 only).

Comment: thank u very much for your answer! in trying to use ffmpeg but i keep getting black video, do u know what can be the reason?